# How to configure Eclipse for Java Servlets and JSPs

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jsp, servlets, plugins

I am working on jsp. I have eclipse but don't know how to configure it for servlets and jsps. I want to develop and debug my web application. Which plugin should I get and from where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of installing plugins you should download the right version.

Download: [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, 212 MB](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

This one has the Web Development perspective from the [WTP/Web Tools Platform plugin](http://eclipse.org/webtools/).

I'm not sure if an application server like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) is included. Otherwise download it.

Afterwards [add tomcat to eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html). (There are other guides as well, just google them.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to install a server like apache or glasfish or jboss to be able to run jsp and servlets on it I suggest you to download the [oepe eclipse version of oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-11118-521475.html)

it has some additional addons to eclipse like previewing jsp and html pages and displaying  palette for jsf development and suports ADF its greate.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step-by-step guide:

> **Note:** I strongly recommend you to keep the Name of the files, location of the files and folders as described in the tutorial.

---

### Downloading Eclipse & Java

1. Download *Eclipse IDE Luna SR1 Packages* version (I recommend this version specifically only because I have tried setting up this version with following JDK and Tomcat versions below, and it works)

> Eclipse: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/luna/sr1
> 2. Download JDK version 8u25 version from here: https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html

> **Tip:** You will find a hundred versions of JDK in the link above! Just <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> and search "8u25".

3. Download Apache Tomcat version 8.0.18 from here: https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.18/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.18-windows-x64.zip

---

### Installation & Set up

1. Extract downloaded Eclipse .zip file and save it somewhere you'll remember it.
2. Extract the downloaded Tomcat version and rename the extracted folder to **Tomcat8.0**
3. Paste the Tomcat8.0 to local disk *C:/*
4. Extract downloaded Java JDK file and install it with default file
   installation location (C:\Program Files\Java).
5. Now, you have to setup *environment variables*

Here's how you can setup *environment variables* in Windows 10. (I assume same goes for Win 7/8)

1. Open *Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings(On the right side panel) > Advanced (Tab) > Environment Variables..*
2. In the bottom section called "System Variables", click **New..** and add 3 different variable setups with the given Variable Name and Variable Value as follows:

**NOTE: If you installed JDK and Tomcat somewhere else, then you will have to enter the full path of the updated location below in the Variable Values.**

For JDK

> Variable Name : JAVA_HOME

> Variable Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

For JRE, add another variable

> Variable Name : JRE_HOME

> Variable Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25

For Tomcat, add another catalina variable

> Variable Name : CATALINA_HOME

> Variable Value : C:\Tomcat8.0

---

### Set up Eclipse for Dynamic Web Development

1. Open *eclipse.exe* from the directory you Extracted and Saved it
2. Navigate to *Help > Install New Software..*
3. Enter "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna" in ***Work with:*** and hit enter
4. Under "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development", select the following options and install them

   Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

   Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools

   Eclipse Web Developer Tools

   JST Server Adapters

   JST Server Adapters Extensions

   JST Server U
5. Restart Eclipse when prompted after installation

Now, you can create a Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse!

6. Go to *File > New > Other > under Web > Dynamic Web Application*
7. Enter a project name and click Next
8. You can change the Content Directory name (WebContent) to whatever name you prefer; but here, I am keeping it as **WebContent** for now.
9. Click on *Finish*
10. In the Project Explorer, right click on *WebContent > New > JSP File* and add any content you like to it, and save the Project. Name JSP file to "example.jsp"
11. Open the **eclipse workspace location** (usually located at *C:\Users%YourName%\Documents\Java\WORKSPACE*)
12. Copy the *WebContent* folder and paste it into *C: > Tomcat8.0 > webapps*

---

### Running the Project on Apache Tomcat

- Open Command Prompt (CMD) *Start > (type in) CMD > Open*
- Navigate to *C:/Tomcate8.0/bin/startup.bat* and return it [If you want to stop Tomcat from running, then run *shutdown.bat* which is located in the same directory as *startup.bat*]

> **Tip:** You can Run/Stop Tomcat from *services.msc* (Start key + R > services.msc > Tomcat8.0 >  Stop/Start)

- Now, go to `http://localhost:8080/` on your browser and you should see the menu of Tomcat.
- Click on Manager App on the right side panel and enter **Admin** as the Username and leave the Password blank.
- Click on *WebContent*
- You should now see the content of your example.jsp file that you created in Eclipse Dynamic Web Project.
- For every changes made in the example.jsp, you must copy and paste the *WebContent* folder from eclipse workspace to *Tomcate > webapps* folder; and restart Apache Tomcat server.

> **Tip:** You can RESTART Tomcat from *services.msc* (Start key + R > services.msc > Tomcat8.0 >  Stop/Start)